# How to plot and print the maximum value in a ContourListPlot[]

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, manipulate, maximum

I have managed to manipulate functions from a list of data points.
The data table is large and thus is in this *[link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/l9cnpk8udbjdlrg/util.dat?dl=0)*.

```
data = Import["util.dat"]
Clear[utl]
utl[x1_, g_, G_] := 
 1/(1 + Exp[(4.39445/(g - G)) x1 + (2.19722 (g + G)/(G - g))])
Manipulate[ListContourPlot[
  {#[[1]], #[[2]], 
     utl[#[[3]], g1, G1]* utl[#[[4]], g2, G2]*utl[#[[5]], g3, G3]} & /@
    data, PlotLegends -> Automatic
  ], {g1, 0.001, 10, 0.001}, {G1, 0.01, 10, 0.001}, {g2, 0.001, 10, 
  0.001}, {G2, 0.01, 10, 0.001}, {g3, 0.001, 10, 0.001}, {G3, 0.01, 
  10, 0.001}]
```

An example of representation giving parameters `g1,G1,g2,G2,g3,G3` can be the following:

[image]

I would like is to plot the point of the maximum value of the `utl[]` function and to get the numbers of the first and second columns from `data` (the coordinates in the ListContourPlot[]) of that point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DynamicModule[{position, max, point}, 
 Manipulate[
  position = 
   Last@Ordering[(utl[#[[3]], g1, G1]*utl[#[[4]], g2, G2]*
         utl[#[[5]], g3, G3]) & /@ data]; 
  max = (utl[#[[3]], g1, G1]*utl[#[[4]], g2, G2]*
       utl[#[[5]], g3, G3]) &@data[[position]]; 
  point = data[[position, {1, 2}]]; 
  ListContourPlot[{#[[1]], #[[2]], 
      utl[#[[3]], g1, G1]*utl[#[[4]], g2, G2]*utl[#[[5]], g3, G3]} & /@
     data, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
   Epilog -> {PointSize[Medium], Red, Point[point]}, 
   PlotLabel -> 
    StringTemplate["Maximum is `` at ``"][ToString[max], 
     ToString[point]]], {{g1, 1.2}, 0.001, 10, 0.001}, {{G1, 1.44}, 
   0.01, 10, 0.001}, {{g2, 0.23}, 0.001, 10, 0.001}, {{G2, 0.5}, 0.01,
    10, 0.001}, {{g3, 0.048}, 0.001, 10, 0.001}, {{G3, 0.063}, 0.01, 
   10, 0.001}]]
```

[image]